# Limiting the number of friend-of-a-friend results in a Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a weighted neo4j graph of books preferences by Alice, Bob, Charlie and Dan:

```
  CREATE (alice:Person {name:'Alice'})
  CREATE (bob:Person {name: 'Bob'})
  CREATE (charlie:Person {name: 'Charlie'})
  CREATE (dan:Person {name: 'Dan'})
  CREATE (b00:Book {title:'Book 00'})
  CREATE (b01:Book {title:'Book 01'})
  CREATE (b02:Book {title:'Book 02'})
  CREATE (b03:Book {title:'Book 03'})
  CREATE (b04:Book {title:'Book 04'})
  CREATE (b05:Book {title:'Book 05'})
  CREATE (b06:Book {title:'Book 06'})
  CREATE (b07:Book {title:'Book 07'})
  CREATE (b08:Book {title:'Book 08'})
  CREATE (b09:Book {title:'Book 09'})
  CREATE (b10:Book {title:'Book 10'})

  CREATE (alice)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.1}]->(b01)
  CREATE (alice)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.2}]->(b02)
  CREATE (alice)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.3}]->(b03)

  CREATE (bob)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.2}]->(b02)
  CREATE (bob)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.4}]->(b04)
  CREATE (bob)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.5}]->(b05)
  CREATE (bob)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.6}]->(b06)
  CREATE (bob)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.7}]->(b07)

  CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.3}]->(b03)
  CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.8}]->(b08)
  CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.9}]->(b09)
  CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:1.0}]->(b10)

  CREATE (dan)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.1}]->(b01)
  CREATE (dan)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.8}]->(b08)
```

[image: graph drawing]

I would like to suggest books to Alice in such a way that I only consider top 2 `LOVES` relationships per each person.
Thus, for Alice, I would only look at "Book 02" and "Book 03" (top-2 books). These books will connect me to Bob and Charlie (and not Dan, who is connected to Alice through her least favorite book). 
In turn, Bob will connect Alice to "Book 06" and "Book 07"; Charlie will connect Alice to 
"Book 09" and "Book 10". At the end, I would like to see four recommendations:
"Book 06" and "Book 07" via Bob; and "Book 09" and "Book 10" via Charlie. What is the most effective and efficient Neo4j query for this task?

Here's what I tried to do:

```
  MATCH (alice:Person {name:'Alice'})-[la:LOVES]->(ba:Book)<-[lf:LOVES]-(friend:Person)
  WITH alice, la
  ORDER BY la.how_much DESC
  WITH alice, COLLECT(la)[0..2] as alice_likes
  UNWIND alice_likes as la
  return *
```

This how I limit the query to the top 2 Alice's likes. However, I don't know how 
to continue the task. I try to do the following, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
  MATCH (alice:Person {name:'Alice'})-[la:LOVES]->(ba:Book)<-[lf:LOVES]-(friend:Person)
  WITH alice, la
  ORDER BY la.how_much DESC
  WITH alice, COLLECT(la)[0..2] as alice_likes
  UNWIND alice_likes as la


  MATCH (alice)-[la]->(ba:Book)<-[lf:LOVES]-(friend:Person)
  WITH alice, la, lf, friend
  ORDER by friend.name,  lf.how_much DESC
  WITH friend, collect(lf)[0..2] as friend_likes, collect(la)[0..2] as alice_likes
  RETURN friend.name, friend_likes, alice_likes
```

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE` clauses for the relationships involving Charlie and Dan.

Comment: you are right, @cybersam, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (alice:Person { name:'Alice' })-[la:LOVES]->(:Book)<-[:LOVES]-(friend:Person)
WITH alice, la, friend
ORDER BY la.how_much DESC 
LIMIT 2
MATCH (bf:Book)<-[lf:LOVES]-(friend:Person)
WITH alice, lf, bf, friend
ORDER BY lf.how_much DESC 
RETURN alice, friend, COLLECT(bf)[..2] AS books;
```

There is presumably only one node for `ALice`, so we can use use `LIMIT 2` to get the top 2 books for her.

However, there can be multiple "friends" who also love those 2 books, so you cannot use `LIMIT 2` to get the 2 books for each of them (instead, you'd only get the top 2 books for them as a group). To get the results you want, this query aggregates the top books for each friend and then picks the top 2 (again, for each friend).

Comment: This will not work if Charlie loves Books 1, 2, and 3 too

    CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.2}]->(b02)
    CREATE (charlie)-[:LOVES {how_much:0.2}]->(b01)

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Those 2 clauses would introduce the lowest `how_much` values for Charlie, so they should not affect the results. And, in my testing, the results are unchanged, as expected.